# Finding equal elements on a converted comlumn's table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `player_items` and one of it's columns is `attributes`, the thing is this column stores lots of `converted attributes` and I have to convert them using `latin1`. I want to find all `player` items that have the same `verify` attribute.

I use this query to check the attributes

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING( CONVERT( attributes USING latin1 ) FROM 18 ) AS 'keys'
FROM player_items 
WHERE CONVERT( attributes USING latin1 ) LIKE '%verify%'
```

And they look like:

```
!LBChCiYl-mBRnLBvt-RY6qpe43

!hiMrF7c3-78yvKPP3-LLLKq0XC
```

All I want is to find every item that has equal `keys` but I cant write the query to do so.

Comment: what is 'they' that look like something else?

Comment: They are the verify attributes that are shown as keys when I execute that query

Comment: what did you mean when you said 'they'?

Comment: If this is what I think it is; trying to pack multiple unrelated item into a single column, you should either make that column JSON or properly normalize your data.